# bitwise operations for field that more than bigint SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bitwise-operators, biginteger

I have an integer of size 2^120
I need to store this integer in sql server (MS SqlServer).
Because bigint limited by range -2^63 .. 2^63 it not enough for me, I used string to store it.
Now I have a problem with bitwise operations for this field.

have any ideas ?

```
SELECT CAST('9223372036854775800' as BIGINT)  --2^63
SELECT CAST('18446744073709552000' as BIGINT) --2^64 
--2^64 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint. 
-- how i use it
CAST("mssql_ace"."permissions" AS BIGINT) & 1
```

Comment: Would it be possible to change your data structure? Looks like you are doing something with permissions + bitmask?

Comment: you can try decimal instead of string  - SELECT CAST('18446744073709552000' as  DECIMAL(38,0))

Comment: yes i am use it for permissions. i can change data structure, but i don't know on what change. i think maybe split one column on two columns (2^64) + (2^64)

Comment: SELECT CAST('18446744073709552000' as DECIMAL(38,0)), Oo it not throw exception, i go think and try implement it

Comment: Decimal won't work with bitwise operators: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql

Comment: .......oh sadly

Comment: You can also explore binary\ varbinary \ varbinary(max)  data type to do this

Comment: Since you can't OR (var)binary datatypes that won't help much either. One fairly inefficient solution would be to use a string of 1's and 0's and use substring to see if position x is 1 or 0. That said, the most straightforward solution would be to go with 120 columns of type bit off course =)